# Why does debugging Blazor client-side opens in a different browser window?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am new to Blazor development. When I first create a Blazor WebAssembly app and debug it on IIS, the app opens in the browser (Chrome), however, it opens on a new window where I am not signed in. This behavior is different from ASP.NET MVC apps or even Blazor server-side apps.

I am trying to understand why is this the case, will it behave like this all the time, is this changeable, and whether or not I should use it. I couldn't find any resource about this on the internet.

Comment: You can open it in a tab on the same window you are using, it will work normally, but I also don't know why it opens in a new window.

Comment: Any updates on this? 
I'm experiencing the same issue